# Show a linear transformation is impossible

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I want to prove a linear transformation, from $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^3}$. So for example, $f(1, 1) = (-2 3, 4), f(-1, 1)=(1, 2, 3), f(3, 1)=(1, -1, 1)$ is not possible. DNE. First of all, I don't know where to start, because I am not very close to know linear transformations.

Comment: Is your function meant to be $f(1,1)=(-2,3,4)$?

Comment: $f(1,1) = (-23,4)$ is not possible because the range of $f$ is $\mathbb R^3$ but $(-23,4) \in \mathbb R^2$. Otherwise note that for linear transformations, $f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b), f(\lambda a) = \lambda f(a), and f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Do you know about the rank of a linear transformation? What is it's maximum possible value?

Comment: If $f(1,1)$ is supposed to be $(-2,3,4)$ then use the fact that $(3,1)=2(1,1)-(-1,1)$ and check that linearity is violated.

Comment: If you're curious how a more general problem can be solved (perhaps not always by hand), note that any linear $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ has a standard matrix.  If you want to investigate whether you can find a linear $f$ with $f(v_i) = w_i$ holding for all $i$ (where $v_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $w_i \in \mathbb{R}^m$ are $i$ given pairs of vectors), this is a system of linear equations in the (unknown) entries of $f$. Its consistency can be evaluated mechanically with matrix algebra. (Telling a computer what matrices to use in that computation may take some thought, but no creativity.)

Comment: Yes, it was $(-2, 3,4)$. I found it. Thank you for help.